# Class loader issue - duplicate class definition for name -LinkageError

Tags: java, class, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have created a class with the following attributes and methods.

I think there is a fundamental issue with my implementation. When I import this signalwrapper class into my test framework, I receive the following error - LinkageError Duplicate class definition.

Tried rebuilding and even creating a new workspace to resolve the duplication, but nothing hasn't worked so far.

Can someone point out the issue?

```
public class Signalwrapper  {

    // Main Signalwrapper attributes 
    public enum Configuration {
        Parken_High, TVHigh, RVC_eSmart
    }

    public enum Signal {
        s_vps_PaCoMainState,
        s_en_APS_PaCo_WarningTones__possible,
        s_en_APS_PaCo_WarningTones__not_possible
    }

    private static Configuration configuration;
    private static Map<Signal, BaseSignalType> signalInstances = new HashMap<>();


    /////////////////// AUTOMATION //////////////////////////////

    // When Config is set - Signals are automatically triggred - set to the Default intilaize values
    public static void setConfiguration(Configuration config) {
        configuration = config;
        initializeSignals();
    }

    // Automation Opputunity - Signal Objects being automatically instnaced once the Config is set 
    private static void initializeSignals() {
        // Initialize and store instances 
        signalInstances.put(Signal.s_vps_PaCoMainState, new s_vps_PaCoMainState());
        
        //signalInstances.put(Signal.s_en_APS_PaCo_WarningTones__possible, new s_en_APS_PaCo_WarningTones__possible());
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    //IN PROGRESS

    // Romans Preference 
    // COnvinence method to reduce multiple dictionary suggestion in main or excuting 
    public static BaseSignalType s_vps_PaCoMainState() {
        return getSignalInstance(Signal.s_vps_PaCoMainState);
    }

    public static BaseSignalType s_en_APS_PaCo_WarningTones__possible() {
        return getSignalInstance(Signal.s_en_APS_PaCo_WarningTones__possible);
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////




    public static BaseSignalType getSignalInstance(Signal signalType) {
        return signalInstances.get(signalType);
    }

    public static Configuration getConfiguration() {
        return configuration;
    }


    // BaseSignalType - nested
    public abstract static class BaseSignalType {
        protected AllSignals allSignals;
        protected int waitTime;
        //**Debugging
        //protected UInt8SignalValue busSignal;
        protected int busSignal;
        protected UInt8SignalValue checkSignal;
        protected boolean isSet;

        public BaseSignalType() {
            initialize(); // Call within constructor //Not sure if it might cause other issues 
        }

        public abstract void initialize();

        //**Debugging - change it back to UInt8SignalValue
        public int getBusSignal() {
            return this.busSignal;
        }

        public UInt8SignalValue getCheckSignal() {
            return this.checkSignal;
        }

        public int setBusSignal(int setValue){
            this.busSignal = setValue;
            return this.busSignal;
        }

        public boolean isSet() {
            return this.isSet;
        }

    }

    //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Config Dependant Example  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


    public static class s_vps_PaCoMainState extends BaseSignalType {
        @Override // Overridiing initialise as our requirment - Config Dependency for OPS Stuff
        public void initialize() {
            //  initialization logic based on the configuration
            switch (Signalwrapper.getConfiguration()) {
                case TVHigh:
//                  this.busSignal = allSignals.VLAN_FAS_0x2_HCP2_1_HCP5__SK_VPS_01_mFAS__VPS_01__VPS_PaCo_MainState; // Replace with actual signal for TVHigh
//                  this.checkSignal = allSignals.VLAN_Komfort_0x5_HCP5_HCP4__SK_VPS_01_mFAS__VPS_01__VPS_PaCo_MainState;
                    //this.checkSignal = 
                    this.waitTime = 1000;
                    break;
                case RVC_eSmart:
                    //***Debugging 
                    this.busSignal = 5;
//                    this.busSignal = allSignals.VLAN_FAS_0x2_RVC_eSmart_HCP5__SK_VPS_01_UmfKam_H__VPS_01__VPS_PaCo_MainState;
//                    this.isSet = this.busSignal.setValue((short) 1); 
                    
                    //*** TEsting
                    this.checkSignal = allSignals.VLAN_FAS_0x2_RVC_eSmart_HCP5__SK_VPS_01_UmfKam_H__VPS_01__VPS_PaCo_MainState;
                    //this.isSet = this.checkSignal.setValue((short) 1);
                    //this.isSet = true;// Set the value to 1
                    //sleep(1000);
                    this.waitTime = 800;
                    break;
                case Parken_High:
                    break;
                default:
                    // Default 
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static class s_en_APS_PaCo_WarningTones__possible extends BaseSignalType {
        @Override
        public void initialize() {
            //this.checkSignal = allSignals.VLAN_Komfort_0x5_HCP4_HCP5__SK_BCM1_03__Parkhilfe_04__OPS_PB_PaCo_WarningTones;
            //this.checkSignal.setValue((short) 1);

            this.busSignal = 21;
            this.checkSignal = null;
            //sleep(1000); // Messina TEstcase Sleep is giving trouble - works only under run()
            //Workaround
//            try {
//                Thread.sleep(1000); // Sleep for 1 second
//            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
```

Signalwrapper.setConfiguration(Signalwrapper.Configuration.RVC_eSmart);

main code, which should automatically initialise vps mainstate class. I receive the linkage error whenever I try to import the library to my testframe work which runs on java - Eclipse IDE.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KITS.png)

BTW I am a humble beginner to programming -- your advice and help is much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).